# 0 NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME cannot be resolved or is not a field with Linux + Eclipse + Java

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, opencv

I get an error on Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME like so:

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME cannot be resolved or is not a field

at MyVideoCap.main(MyVideoCap.java:7)
```

I had settled the NativLibrary path at the following location.
    /home/.../OpenCV/opencv-2.4.5/build/lib

I had followed the instruction on https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers but it doesn't creates any opencv2.4.9.jar file I am working on ubuntu 12 and eclipse with opencv api suppoert.

so help me if you can to generating and building the jar file in the build directory in ubuntu.  thanks in advance...

Comment: “Unresolved compilation problem” means that compiling your .java file has failed. You native libraries have nothing to do with that. Open `MyVideoCap.java` in Eclipse and look at the red underlined part.

Comment: Actually there is some problem with the native library in build directory which is created it contains only the executable files there are no OpenCVXXX.jar file what can I do to solve the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the full Installing progress of the OpenCV...

**# install basic development environment**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
```

**# install opencv dependencies. ubuntu 13.04 ships with opencv which is close enough to 2.4.6 to pull in most of the needed dependencies.**

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libopencv-dev
```

**# additional dependencies for java support**

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk ant
```

**# compile opencv**

```
tar xzvf opencv-2.4.6.1.tar.gz

cd opencv-2.4.6.1

mkdir build; cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON ..

make

sudo make install
```

**And in last don't forget to set Native library path to the**

```
/home/.../opencv-2.4.6.1/build/lib
```

Thats it...