# NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, opengl

I am creating a face detection program using open Graphics Library in java through eclipse 4.5.0 and a jar file is added to the java project for open CV 2.4.1 as well as i had tried all the methods as specified on web for setting the location of NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME through the build path option available in eclipse IDE,but still can't find the solution... please help me to solve this error

**My Java File for Face Detection**

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetection 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetection.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
        Mat image = Highgui
                .imread(FaceDetection.class.getResource("shekhar.JPG").getPath());

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) 
        {
            Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        String filename = "ouput.png";
        System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
    }
}
```

**I have followed this link**
https://blog.openshift.com/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers/

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379814/0-native-library-name-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-with-linux-eclipse Check that the JAR contains org.opencv.core.Core, it hasn't been removed from this API: http://docs.opencv.org/java/index.html?org/opencv/core/Core.html Ensure that you use the right native library for your architecture and your operating system. If you use a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS, you must use the 32-bit native libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As you have provided the jar file of OpenCV but not configured the Native library location.

You need to install OpenCV in your machine first and provide the path of jar file in build path using folder created after installation of the OpenCV (or use jar file that you have downloaded.) and also location of Native library location should be "opencv-2.4.7/build/lib folder" .

Link to download OpenCV - https://opencv.org/releases.html

Please refer this link for configuring eclipse - http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html

Comment: did you try the answer?